# Does a ZF2 application with 2 DBs imply overhead?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

There's this ZF2 application that has access to two different databases.
Every Request **can** access both DBs, but there is only one page that will actually do that, because it is needed.

Will those 2 DBs and their adapters imply overhead to my entire application or will it make a difference only where I actually use them both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, as always: It Depends.

If you factory your dependencies properly, you will only build the 2nd connection when it is needed, and you won't have that overhead everywhere. Additionally, if building that object is a real performance hit (I wouldn't assume so, but I don't know your app), you can build a proxy of the object instead and have the real object created ONLY when you attempt to use it.

In a well designed app, there is no unreasonable overhead for adding datasource factories that don't get booted.

Simply stated, if designed correctly, it should only make a difference when you try to use them both.